# Arch Linux class network problem

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I have a following problem. I've installed Arch Linux on 17 computers in one room, all connected to one Cisco switch. (Intel NUC5PPY, with 120GB SSD and 4GB RAM).

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #2 (rev 21)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #3 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

When I start one computer, login and ping 8.8.8.8 it usually work well, but when I turn on more computers, then problem starts - ping start to have huge packet loss. Every computer is on 1000Mb/s ethernet, conected via cable (CAT5).

No (network) error loged, no disconecting link in dmesg.

End of ping stdout:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=874 ttl=59 time=5.10 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=875 ttl=59 time=6.15 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
875 packets transmitted, 549 received, 37% packet loss, time 879408ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.972/3.114/12.649/1.729 ms
```

When i connect any other computer (for example my ThinkPad X240) to any switch ports, internet works without problem, no packet loss.

Comment: ... restart/reboot the switch/hardware first, before analysing logs etc. Sometimes that's just it :)

Comment: Do these boxes get their addresses from DHCP? If not, have you any conflicts? What about MAC address conflicts?

Comment: @MichaelD. restarted serveral times, I've also changed swich. Thnaks for comment.

Comment: @roaima Addresses are from DHCP, MAC should be uniqe, I have never changed them. But I'll check. Thanks for comment.

Comment: By DHCP server log there are unique MACs and IPs.

Comment: How many machines and how many IPs available?

Comment: Network mask is 255.255.252.0, but there are about 200x 3 in DHCP pools, rest is static or unassigned by different reasons. And there are about 150 computers in whole network. Thanks for comment @schaiba

Comment: Update: I've updated machines, changed switch, updated BIOS and no progres. I'll try other distribution.